# Where are the source shared files since the steam pipe update?

Tags: steam, source-engine

I used to do a little mapping and modding but I had to stop due to real life. Now I'm doing some gmod stuff and I was wondering where the source shared files have gone.

The files used to be called:

```
source 2007 shared materials.gcf
source 2007 shared models.gcf
source 2007 shared sounds.gcf
source materials.gcf
source models.gcf
source sounds.gcf
```

but they may have changed to vpk files since then...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and here is what I found. Since the SteamPipe update, .GCF files are not used anymore by Steam. Instead, content is packed into .VPK files.

Source: [Source engine games on SteamPipe](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7388-QPFN-2491)

Now, to locate different files you may need to modify (in order to create a mod for example), you need to navigate to (example given for Half-Life 2, so for Garry's Mod you need to change the folder's name):

steamapps\common\Half-Life 2\hl2\resource.

Here you can find all the .RES files, which can be modified with a text editor. In my case, it was the gamemenu.res file, to modify items on the game menu.

Also, here is a Steam Support forum thread that helped me :

[What happened to GCF's?](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3143194)

All the questions you may have are answered in the first link I gave (Steam Support).

Answer (score 0):

No, those files don't exist anymore and there is no replacement. There are also no shared models and materials anymore. Each game fully downloads everything it needs since the steam pipe updates.

Comment: Source for this? I thought the entire point of the Source SDKs was to avoid having to duplicate downloaded data for each Source game.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie There are a lot of vpk's in the vpk folder of the SDK Base Folder, if that is what he is asking.  But for the games there are no shared files anymore. I cannot tell which vpk contains what though.

Comment: I don't think this is correct, as I opened up the garrysmod_dir.vpk file and it doesn't contain half of the files that gmod uses. Additionally, Garry has made numerous blog posts about the "mounting" system that gmod uses to load content from other games. This is why you still need to own CS:S in order to get those materials/sounds/other resources for gmod. The issue is I don't know where the base content is stored.

Comment: @YM_Industries Garry's Mod is the exception, not the rule.  The HL2 shared files are now stored separately for each Valve game that uses them.  If you don't believe me, download Counter-Strike Source then look in its hl2 directory.  You'll see the formerly-shared HL2 vpks in it: `hl2_misc_dir.vpk`, `hl2_sound_misc_dir.vpk`, `hl2_sound_vo_english_dir.vpk`, and `hl2_textures_dir.vpk`.